# Journey Builder - Populations / Injecting New Subscribers

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, marketing-cloud-connect

Scenario: New leads are being added into a Salesforce.com instance, and as a result are being injected into a Marketing Cloud Journey Interaction. These are always new leads, unknown in the Marketing Cloud instance.

Problem: Since these are new subscribers, they won't be in the All Subscribers list. In the old system, I would have just marked this Data Extension as Root, and added the email address to the Channel Address Order. This system has been replaced with Populations.

With Populations, I am not seeing the ability to use the resulting Salesforce Journey Data Extension as the base. Meaning I can't use this Data Extension which is really the only source I need for new subscribers. So with the subscribers not being in the All Subscribers list and this Data Extension not marked as root, subscribers are failing on the first email interaction.

I feel as though this is a somewhat common use-case being describing, so I am hoping I am just missing something obvious with this new system. Does anybody have the way around this?

BONUS: If a Lead converts to a Contact midway through a Journey, will emails still be sent to the Lead instance of their subscriber?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thankfully it did turn out to a simple issue I was overlooking -- the emails were not failing because the Lead wasn't on the All Subscribers list, they were failing because our test account has a Required Profile Attribute with no default value (never use required attributes).

Support was able to confirm that all Data Extensions created from a Salesforce Entry Event are by default marked as root.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Can you synchronize the Lead object using the Connector?
If so, you could create a new DE with a Primary Key, which is mandatory to use in populations, and populate it with a query definition from the Salesforce Journey Data Extension.

Comment: Thank you for response, one of the options I looked into, but since they only synchronize every 15 minutes there is the chance that new subscribers will be missed.